# Laravel whereBetween and Exporting result to CSV

Tags: php, laravel, csv, laravel-5

I'm using [Matt Stauffer](https://mattstauffer.co/blog/export-an-eloquent-collection-to-a-csv-with-league-csv) CSV export package. 
Using `Reporting::all()` I get the expected result and the CSV report is downlooaded successfully. But using the below code I only get empty result. Just the csv file with columns, not a single row.

```
public function export($from, $to)
{
    $reports = Reporting::whereBetween('reportDate',[date('m-d-Y', $from), date('m-d-Y', $to)]);

    $csv = \League\Csv\Writer::createFromFileObject(new \SplTempFileObject());

    $csv->insertOne(\Schema::getColumnListing('reports'));

    foreach ($reports as $rep) {
        $csv->insertOne($rep->toArray());
    }

    //return \Response::download($csv->output('reports.csv'));
    return $csv->output('reports.csv');
}
```

Is there anything wrong I'm doing in the `whereBetween` condition?

Comment: If your `reportDate` field is e.g. a standard MySQL date field, then the date format is `Y-m-d`, not `m-d-Y`,

Comment: The `reportDate` is Unix Timestamp format.

Comment: Great, I'll post an answer. :)

Comment: you are missing `get()`

Comment: Oh! Thanks a lot @ABDEL-RHMAN, I missed that out and that was exactly it. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Since your `reportDate` field is in unix timestamp format, you need to supply two unix timestamps. If `$from` and `$to` is already in unix timestamp form, you don't need to do anything to them. Otherwise, convert them through e.g. `strtotime()`.